# Trigger polling using htmx.trigger

Tags: htmx

I'm trying to trigger a **polling** behavior on a `div` using JavaScript.

This is the `div`.

```
<div id="myId" hx-get="https://xxxx" hx-swap="innerHTML"></div>
```

This is the trigger function.

```
 htmx.trigger(
   htmx.find(`#myId`),
   "every 300ms"
 );
```

But it's not working. Is there a way to obtain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your JavaScript set up the polling interval. Then you can trigger a custom event and have your `div` listen for it.

To have the server stop the client polling, put a different custom event in the [Response Headers](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) and listen for it on the client. Included is how you would add the response header if your server was ASP.NET, since I'm not sure what you are running server-side. Also `innerHTML` is the default hx-swap target, so could be omitted.

HTMX:

```
<div id="myId" hx-get="https://xxxx" hx-trigger="myEvent"></div>
```

JS:

```
// start polling
function startpolling(){
var myPoller= setInterval(function () {  htmx.trigger("myId","myEvent"); }, 300);
}

// stop polling
document.body.addEventListener("stopPolling", function(evt){
    clearInterval(myPoller);
})
```

ASP.NET Server code:

```
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("HX-Trigger", "stopPolling");
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! 
I already thought about that but there is the problem that you can't really stop the polling from the server with the 286 code.

[docs](https://htmx.org/docs/#polling)

Have you found a solution for that?
How to do you stop the `setInterval`?

Comment: Hi Luca, I updated the answer to include how the server would tell the client to stop polling. The response code 286 is just a novel response code made up by the author HTMX. It is not required to send a 286 to the client unless you are using the standard `hx-trigger` attribute on your `div` element. In your case where you're calling htmx outside of the standard way, the custom header in the server Response should suffice to allow you to capture the custom response.

Comment: Thank you for the update! 
It seems the most sensible approach 